# How odoo POS Working

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, point-of-sale

I want to know how odoo pos working in offline. I checked other resources but i cant found anything.I cant find anything in their official site or nothing found in any other site.

Comment: Well, by saving data on the client side and sending them to the server when the connection is restored. Is there a particular function of the POS that you want to know more about ?

Comment: Yes thats what i want to know.

Comment: have you seen the docs

Comment: yes but i can't find about POS technically.

Comment: Have you built the software already?

Answer (score 4):

inside every browser there is cache memory so..
the pos stores the data in the cache memory of the browser called DOM( Document Object Model) so, it saves the data as the object.
like in the pos there is order so, it creates the object of order in the DOM and saves the customer detail in it as same as for the cart item it stores that in DOM.

and there is a javascript method which calls the actual code in server so, that order get saved and processed. but if the connection is loss or nework not available then it storing data to that cache means DOM.. and when it get connection because it pinging at every perticualar time interval it sends all this stored data to the server and process it.

in short it is a magic of javascript.

Comment: I cant see anything with browser console?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to tell you ..
you need to install "Firebug" plugin for that in browser.
after install by pressing F12 you can see the DOM tab in that you can find the objects of the POS.

Comment: in firefox there is DOM but for other i am not sure.

Comment: Is there any other useful links for more details

Comment: for what ...?
about POS or DOM.?

Comment: DOM how used in POS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135752/discussion-between-viki-chavada-and-yasar-arafath).

Comment: Your answer is very helpful for me.